# daily script struggle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to insert data into the `daily_stats` table which has the following rows

```
submission_date
message_class
channel
data_centre
line_of_business
submission_vol
```

from the `Payld_Data.Received_Messages` table but i want my script to insert the data in daily for messages only on that day the script runs

ive written something below but how do i add in the dates for it to only add in the messages received daily?

```
insert into daily_stats values (trunc(submission_date), Message_Class, Channel, data_centre, Line_Of_Business, submission_vol(*))
Select trunc(A.submission_date), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business, submission_vol(*) 
From Payld_Data.Received_Messages A, Recon_Data.Reconciliation_Control B
Where A.Conversation_Id = B.Conversation_Id
group by Trunc(A.Creation_Timestamp), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business;
```

Comment: I guess this is Oracle? Please add the tag if so. I think the Oracle function for current date is `trunc(sysdate())` but I can't work out where you want to use it

Comment: no its an sql script. I want to insert data into the table that only have yesterdays timestamp how do i do that?

Comment: "sql" is specific to whatever RDBMS it's running against, so it's important to state what RDBMS you are using. The way one deals with dates, or trim's strings is different from database to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing here a bit, since your question isn't terribly clear, that your `Submission_Date` should be the current date (The date upon which you ran this INSERT statement. If that's the case then the following should work:

```
insert into daily_stats (submission_date, Message_Class, Channel, data_centre, Line_Of_Business, submission_vol(*))
Select CURRENT_DATE, A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business, submission_vol(*) 
From Payld_Data.Received_Messages A, Recon_Data.Reconciliation_Control B
Where A.Conversation_Id = B.Conversation_Id
group by Trunc(A.Creation_Timestamp), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business;
```

The big changes here are

1. use `CURRENT_DATE` to get the current date
2. The format `INSERT INTO <table> (List, Of, Fields)` is the right way to write this, notice there is no `VALUE` before the list of fields.
3. I removed the `TRUNC()` function in the list of fields since this purely a list of fields, no transformation/logic allowed. It's in the `SELECT` portion of the query where you do your `Trunc()` and other logic. The `INSERT` portion is there only to specify to which table we are inserting and to which fields (and their order).

You can check out the [page in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/insert-select.html) for `Insert... Select` statements to see the proper syntax.

Comment: thank you, how would i insert yesterdays date rather than current date?

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE - 1` would be yesterday

Comment: do i need brackets?

Comment: Great to hear it!  :)